# How to Combine two nvarchar values in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i want to display 2 values in dropdown list and those two fields are nvarchar.

i have try with following query it is working fine for int but no works for nvarchar because alignment issue

select REPLACE(STR(InventoryID, 3), SPACE(1), '0')  + '  |  ' + Description  from InventoryMaster.

i need this result

[image]

but get

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us your original data please? What value do you want if `InventoryID` = 1234 ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Right(Replicate('0', 11) + Cast(InventoryID As varchar(11)), 11)
     + ' | '
     + Description As field_name
FROM   your_table
```

This will pad your `InventoryID` with leading zeroes, 11 to be exact, as this is the maximum number of "characters" an field of datatype `int` can be (-2,147,483,648).

Then it appends `|` (space, pipe, space) before finally adding the description field